# Send timestamp to firebase using firebase funtions

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I need to save a date has a firebase Timestamp Object to Cloud Firestore using Firebase functions.

The code in question:

```
import FirebaseFunctions

lazy var functions = Functions.functions(region: "europe-west3")

let stamp = Timestamp(date: Date()) —> Not working

self.functions.httpsCallable("userUpdate").call(["id": user.uid, “startDate”: stamp]) { (result, error) in
                if let error = error {
                        print("##### update error \(error)”)
                    }
                }
                
                if let res = result {
                    if let fireData = (res.data as? [String: Any]) {
                        debugPrint("#####  Success update Data -> \(fireData["data"])")
                    }
                }
            }
```

The problem is that Firebase does not recognise the Timestamp format throwing a error:

> 'Unsupported type: FIRTimestamp for value <FIRTimestamp: seconds=1633262425 nanoseconds=843380928>'

If I try to send the date on the format below it works BUT the date on the server has the wrong format, it shows has a string and not has a Timestamp.

```
let date = DateFormatter.localizedString(from: Date(), dateStyle: .short, timeStyle: .none)
```

Any solutions for Firebase to recognise the date I'm sending has a Timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Callable Cloud Functions only know how to send/receive JSON type, and `Timestamp` is not a JSON type.

The easiest way to work around this is to send the [seconds and nanoseconds](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp#seconds) as separate numbers (which are valid JSON types) and then reconstruct a [`Timestamp` object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp.md#timestampconstructor) from those numberzs in the Cloud Functions code.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand, how do you build the object in that way?

Comment: You can pass the seconds and nanoseconds to the `Timestamp` constructor on the server. I linked the JavaScript docs, but the same constructor should exist in Node.js.

Comment: "Pass the objects on the server" I'm confused since I'm trying to accomplish the task with iOS swift, I don't know what to do with JavaScript or Node.js

Comment: Who wrote the `userUpdate` function? What value do they expect for the `startDate` parameter?

Comment: The backend guy :)  they expect a Timestamp, is that even possible to send from my side?

Comment: As said: you can only pass JSON types to callable functions, and Firestore's `Timestamp` is not a native JSON type. If the backend guy just said "timestamp" without specifying, they might just have meant a timestamp-in-milliseconds, which is more common outside of Firestore/iOS. That would just be a numeric value (the number of milliseconds since the start of the epoch) and you'd get it in Swift with `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000`.